# Remove or Replace Server Header in Swoole WebSocket Response

Tags: security, websocket, openswoole

I have created a Swoole WebSocket server using the example given on the official OpenSwoole website:

[https://openswoole.com/docs/modules/swoole-websocket-server#quick-start-example](https://Connection%20%09Upgrade%20Sec-WebSocket-Accept%20%09mIqWL0joEU/Z/yDXqmtfa3+N2sI=%20Sec-WebSocket-Version%20%0913%20Server%20%09OpenSwoole%204.11.1%20Upgrade%20%09websocket)

The response header returned by the server to the client contains the *Server: OpenSwoole 4.11.1* entry.

```
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: mABCD0joUS/Z/yPYqrqfa3+I2sT=
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Server: OpenSwoole 4.11.1
Upgrade: websocket
```

Could we remove this server header line completely or replace it with a fake name like *Server: XYZ*?